# Is there a hook in WordPress that I can use to filter the output of a specific shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

Is there a hook in WordPress that I can use to filter the output of a specific shortcode? for example:

there is a shortcode in onother plugin like this:

```
add_shortcode('mytoopsh', 'wporg_shortcode');
function wporg_shortcode( $atts = [], $content = null) {
    echo 'hi shortcod';
    return $content;
}
```

This short code is used in another program plugin and

I want to get the output of the above shortcode and modify it and replace it in the same place as before.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem by php output buffering. Before the output, I get the code shortcodes and convert them into lowercase letters:

```
ini_set('output_buffering', 'on'); // turns on output_buffering
function remove_meta_generators($html)
{    
       //edit html of page
        return $html;
}

function clean_meta_generators($html)
{
       ob_start('remove_meta_generators');  
}

add_action('get_header', 'clean_meta_generators', 100);
add_action('wp_footer', function () {
    ob_end_flush();
}, 100);
```